# React.createRef :current is null in Internet Explorer but works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, create-ref

I am trying to use `React.createRef`
Current code works in `Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge` but in `IE` `this.calendarRef.curent` is null

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      element = this;
      this.state= {
         allDayText: 'All day',
         direction: '',
         view: this.props.with,
         date: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
      };
       this.cubeRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount(){
       console.log(this.cubeRef);
    }


    <CubeContainer
        ref={this.cubeRef}
    />
```

Comment: Where is `this.calendarRef.curent` in your code?

Comment: @Shlang sorry.  `this.cubeRef.current` is `null` in `componentDidMount`

Comment: `element` is undefined in your code snippet. I made a [code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-acnshd?file=index.js) and `this.cubeRef` won't be null in IE. I can't reproduce the issue with your above code. You could check the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHKV2.png. If the issue still persists, could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You could use some online code editor like stackblitz.

Comment: I can't open your snippet in `IE`. The error codes are `SCRIPT1002` and `SCRIPT5009`.

Comment: Yes, I can't find an online React code editor which can be opened in IE. You could check the code sample in other browsers and run the same code locally in IE. I also run the same code locally and get the result.